# The difference between a set and a subset.

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently taking real analysis, and I'm afraid this might be a very elementary question, but the further I go in the course the more confused I become about the difference between a set in $\mathbb{R}^p$ and a subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Furthermore, sometimes the notes simply say, for example, "$U_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p $". Is $U_n$ a subset or a set?

Finally, what is the notation for a set and a subset, respectively?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A subset is a set; "to be a subset of" is a binary relation : $A \subseteq B$ iff every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$.

Comment: No difference - a subset simply assumes there is a second set to be a subset of, if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a **set** is simply a collection of elements.

By definition, a set $A$ is a **subset** of a set $B$ if and only if every element in $A$ is also in $B$.  In other words, $A \subseteq B$ iff $x \in A$ implies $x \in B$.

Note that every set is in fact a subset.  Because, trivially, $A \subseteq A$ for all sets $A$.  In words, "every set is a subset of itself."

Also, the empty set $\varnothing$ is a subset of every set $A$, because the empty set vacuously satisfies the definition of subset.  In words, "the empty set is a subset of every set."

Oftentimes questions will ask you for examples of nontrivial subsets.  This typically means any subset that is neither the entire set itself nor the empty set.

---

> I am currently taking real analysis, and I'm afraid this might be a very elementary question, but the further I go in the course the more confused I become about the difference between a set in $\mathbb{R}^p$ and a subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$.

"A set in $\Bbb R^p$" and "a subset of $\Bbb R^p$" mean exactly the same thing.

To further expand on that:

If $A$ is "a set in $\Bbb R^p$" then that means all the elements of $A$ are also in $\Bbb R^p$.  So $A$ satisfies the definition of being a subset of $\Bbb R^p$, and we have $A \subseteq \Bbb R^p$.

If $A$ is "a subset of $\Bbb R^p$" then, well, this is just a more direct way of saying exactly the same thing:  $A \subseteq \Bbb R^p$

> Furthermore, sometimes the notes simply say, for example, "$U_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p $". Is $U_n$ a subset or a set?

Both.  $U_n$ is itself a set.  And $U_n$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^p$.  That's actually exactly what the notation means.  When you see something like "$A \subseteq B$" you can read it as "$A$ is a subset of $B$."

> Finally, what is the notation for a set and a subset, respectively?

I'm not entirely sure what you're getting at here but there really isn't any notation for a set, at least not in the same way that there is for subsets.  We generally denote sets with capital letters (except for the empty set, typically denoted $\varnothing$ or $\emptyset$), but this isn't really a hard rule.

Subset-related notation:

$A \subseteq B$ means $A$ is a subset of $B$.

$A \supseteq B$ means $A$ is a superset of $B$ (which is just another way of saying $B$ is a subset of $A$).

Some authors use $\subset$ and $\supset$ instead of $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$, respectively.

The notations $A \nsubseteq B$ and $A \not\subset B$ can be used to indicate $A$ is not a subset of $B$.  There are corresponding superset notations $\nsupseteq$ and $\not\supset$.

The notation $A \subsetneq B$ means $A$ is a **proper subset** of $B$.  This just means that $A \subseteq B$ and $A \ne B$.  There is a corresponding superset notation $\supsetneq$.

Note: Unfortunately, some authors (although I think this is rare these days) use $A \subseteq B$ to indicate $A$ is a subset of $B$ and use $A \subset B$ to indicate $A$ is a proper subset of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

All subsets are sets. But to be a subset is a relation between sets, like numbers being less than or equal to each other. The proper way to say it is "$A$ is a subset *of* $B$", as it doesn't make sense to call a set a subset without specifying what it's a subset of.